# Not able to SUPER HIDE a folder in my laptop

Tags: windows-7

I used the below command to super hide a folder 

attrib +S +H "I:\PrivateFolder" 

But still it just showing as a normal hidden , i'm able to search the files in that folder 
Pls help how to solve this issue

Comment: TIL: `+S +H` = `Super Hide`. ;)

Comment: I assume you're doing this to prevent a particular person from knowing the folder is even there.  That's not possible in Windows.  You can prevent access to a folder, but you cannot make it totally invisible.

Answer (score 4):

Just FYI - `+S +H` **doesn't** "super hide".. it just sets the system and hidden flags for the folder.. there's nothing there to stop the folder being accessible.  Also, these flags can be easily removed by a user.

To do this, you need to look at setting file permissions so that only your user can access them.

Try right click > properties > security (tab) > edit.  Remove all users and then "add" yourself only with "allow full control" set

No other users will be able to access the folder.

That said, they may be able to take ownership of the folder to still get back in.  To avoid this, add any other users and deny full control.

To do this programatically, you need to start looking into the "`icacls`" command
[This page](http://ss64.com/nt/icacls.html) will give you a lot fo help if you decice to go down the icacls route.

Using icacls doesn't make the folder completely bullet proof - only good strong encryption can do that, but to stop the average user getting into your stuff - this will be more than enough.

Hope this helps.

Comment: very true.  Answer updated

Answer (score 0):

You can't hide information like that. The attrib +h command sets a folder to hidden, and +s sets it to system. Although setting rights to a folder may help a little bit, if you only use one user, it won't do much good.

I would recommend to use a program such as truecrypt to create an encrypted folder which you can password protect, or alternatively use something like dropbox and instead of using the client, only work on the web. This means your personal files are only stored in the cloud, and only accessible if you know the password to your dropbox/onedrive/etc account. The disadvantage of the online storage ability is that files are only accessible after you download them, and if you forget to delete the files, they are local.